# Better ways to organize data

Tags: python

So I have the following loop:

```
for temperature in [-40,25,85]:
    for voltage in [24, 28, 32]:
        for power in [50,100,200]:
            #measurement 1
            ...
            #measurement 2
            ...
```

There is a question of how to organize the measured data. Up to now I've been creating a separate folder at each loop for each loop variable, so if I want to grab the data for measurement 1 at -40°C, 28V and 100W, I'll just go to ./-40/28/100. It's been working reasonably well but I cannot help wondering whether there is a better way.

Comment: I would think of using a database (if there are more than those 27 possible combinations) or, using just one folder whose name is composed of the 3 components, for example: `./-40,28,100/`

Comment: At most there could be 3 temperature points, 5 voltage points and maybe 10 power points, leading to 150 combinations. Never done any work on database before, where to begin then, assuming the convenience it brings outweigh the effort to set it up.

Comment: The easiest database to setup (IMO) is [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), you can try it but that will mean learning the query language: SQL. That is the best solution when you want to organize and retrieve data. Otherwise you'll end up with 150 folders.

Comment: IMHO, Database would be an overkill.

Comment: How's PyTables for this application? I'm browsing through its main features now and it seems promising.

Comment: I guess storing values in a text file is as basic as it gets. It all depends on what all functionalities you need with your data.

Comment: FWIW, I believe gdbm and bsddb are easier to get started with than SQLite.  I see nothing wrong with using directories for this amount of data.

Comment: Nothing much, the most likely post-pocessing involves plotting  certain measurement data vs. one or two of the looping variables.

Answer (score 3):

```
import json

dictionary = {}

for temperature in [-40,25,85]:
    for voltage in [24, 28, 32]:
        for power in [50,100,200]:
            #measurement 1
            #measurement 2..
            dictionary[str((temperature,voltage,power))] = (measurement1,measurement2,...)

f = open(".../somefile.txt",'w')
f.write(json.dumps(dictionary,indent=1,sort_keys=True))
f.close()
```

Maybe JSON can help you.

Comment: But if the amount of data is big the memory usage could be a problem. Also file reading can be a performance problem depending on how often the data will be read from the file and its size.

Comment: The data isn't that big, is it? The OP said 150 or so combinations, so I'm guessing pretty small files.

Comment: He said 150 combination (or folders), but made no statement about the data size. Maybe he can clarify this to us?

Comment: Each measurement gives a numerical array the dimension of which normally doesn't exceed 10X10, which will then be saved to a file. So yes, those would be pretty small files.

Comment: In that case @tMJ solution seems reasonable

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the *pandas* module serves my purpose well. By using it I can save all controlling variables and measurement results in one table, which later on can be easily accessible for all kinds of slicing, grouping and plotting.